# Accessing field dependency values in the back end

Tags: metadata, database, dependent-picklist

On our UI we have two picklist fields where we provided field dependancy. On the front end we can see these dependancies. Now at the backend there will be a table to store these values. I would like to know that under-lying table. this part is required for integration with ERP using information

So far we can't directly access our database rather we can use only API to get data from database. Is there other ways to access the database?

My target is to access the back end table where it stores the values of field dependency.

Answer (score 2):

It's a multi-tenant platform so you'll never get that access.  The same database is storing multiple customer's data and data structure.  Salesforce has built a layer on top of the Oracle cluster to function with the multi-tenant nature of the platform.  They provide multiple APIs for grabbing data and metadata alike.

It sounds like you'd be better off looking into the metadata API for what your after (field dependency).  Maybe you can clarify exactly what you're trying to get that would require direct access to the underlying database and I might be able to clarify my answer a little more.

http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/api_meta/

Comment: i agree with that point. My question is": on UI we had two picklist fields where we provided field dependancy. on the front end we can see dependancy.Now at the backend there will be a table to store these values. i would like to know that under lying table. this part is required for integration with ERP using infor ion

Comment: Some metadata is bubbled into the data APIs (e.g. ApexClass, ApexPage, ApexTrigger), but unfortunately the field dependencies are not part of that.  The best you could do is to use the Metadata API to pull that information in.